# How to position an image in tikzposter?

Tags: graphics, tikzposter, size

I want to know how I can position a picture in `tikzposter` class in x and y direction. I use this snippet for pictures in a block:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait,margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\block{Test-Block}{
            \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.6\linewidth}
                \begin{tikzfigure}[Text under pic]
                     \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}
                \end{tikzfigure}
            \end{wrapfigure}
        Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text    
    }

\end{document}
```

Additional, I would like the max. size of the picture in this block. Is there an automatism? How can I achieve the max size in another way without automatism?

**Edit:**

What I need to know is how I can position a picture in tikzposter properly where I want it to be? In this example it is to big for the block and it should be a bit nearer to the right side of the block. How can I achieve this? I thought it would be a good idea to have the possibility to shift it in x and y direction?

Aditionally, I'm not sure weather I have to use "\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]" or "{0.6\linewidth}" in "wrap figure" to increase/decrease picture size?

I Hope it is more clear, now?

Comment: Please add the code of a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why the tikzfigure?  It serves no purpose here.

Comment: The `wrapfigure` isn't useful as well.

Comment: I edited the post and add a proper MWE.

Comment: Tikzpicture is used because of the tikzposter-class. Other possibilities?, I don't know.

Comment: "wrapfigure" is used because I have more text in the block as it is shown here.

Comment: You don't need a tikzpicture to include a picture. You need it to prepare a picture using tikz. The boxes are drawn using tikz for example.

Comment: You don't even need tikzposter to do a poster. You can use `article` with package `tcolorbox`, which i bet will get better results.

Comment: Could you tell me more about your alternative? I thought tikzposter is the easiest way to create a poster with latex. But nevertheless I would like to know how to position an image in x-y coordinates?